# Flutter & Sqflite : resultat null

Tags: flutter, sqflite

I have a Sqflite database to retrieve TEXT values ​​which can be equal to null.

In my list that shows saved values, is it possible to replace values ​​equal to null with 0 rather than NULL?

Thank you

Comment: Please add your current code to the question.

Comment: Sorry,
I made changes in my database and it works as I want.
thank you for your attention